# voronoi diagram is not right

Tags: c, voronoi

I have created a voronoi code which does not work as it was supposed.

I really can't figure the error!!!

The function I am calling is:

```
void Voronoi(

    const int NbPoints,
    const int height,
    const int width,
    float * X,
    float * Y,
    int   * V,
    int   * const ouVoronoi )
{

    float Xd , Yd;
    float Distance ,initDistance = FLT_MAX;
    int Threshold;

    int x , y; // pixel coordinates
    int i;

    for ( y = 0; y < height; y++ )
    {
        for ( x = 0; x < width; x++ )
        {
            //Calculate distances for all the points
            for ( i = 0; i < NbPoints; i++ )
            {
                Xd = X[ i ] - x;
                Yd = Y[ i ] - y;
                Distance = Xd * Xd + Yd * Yd;

                //if this Point is closer , assign proper threshold
                if ( Distance < initDistance )
                {
                    initDistance = Distance;
                    Threshold = V[ i ];
                }

                *( ouVoronoi + ( x + y * width ) ) = Threshold;

            } /* i */
        } /* x */

    } /* y */


}
```

You can find the code [here](http://pastebin.com/5184x9VT)

The image I am receiving:

[image: wrong]

The right image:

[image: right]

Comment: Should `*( ouVoronoi + ( x + y * width ) ) = Threshold;` be *outside of* the loop `for ( i = 0; i < NbPoints; i++ )`?

Comment: @Weather Vane:No, since we are calculating the threshold in this loop and we must fill the ouVoronoi

Comment: Are you sure? I haven't answered your original question, but having that inside the loop is redundant since `i` is not involved. In every iteration of `i` you write `Threshold` to the same place . I suggest doing that once only, after the loop.

Comment: @ Weather Vane:Yes , you are right! ( even though it does not have an impact to the result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to reset `initDistance` for each point, like this

```
...
for ( y = 0; y < height; y++ )
{
    for ( x = 0; x < width; x++ )
    {
        //Calculate distances for all the points
        initDistance = FLT_MAX;                             // <--- added this line
        for ( i = 0; i < NbPoints; i++ )
        {
            Xd = X[ i ] - x;
            Yd = Y[ i ] - y;
            Distance = Xd * Xd + Yd * Yd;

            //if this Point is closer , assign proper threshold
            if ( Distance < initDistance )
            {
                initDistance = Distance;
                Threshold = V[ i ];
            }
        } /* i */
        *( ouVoronoi + ( x + y * width ) ) = Threshold;     // <-- moved out of loop
    } /* x */

} /* y */
...
```

Comment: :Thanks a lot!!Everything is working fine now!I forgot totally the init distance!